# closing the door behind / after someone

Tags: meaning-in-context

I come across this phrase several times while reading a book. But I am not completely clear about its usage.

What would be the physical position of the person about whom the following thing is said -

1. He closed the door behind him.
2. He closed the door after him.

My understanding is -

In first case the person has come inside the room and closed the door.
In second case the person has left the room and closed the door.

Is it correct ?

And how do we use this same phrase when describing someone getting into a car ?

1. He got in the car and closed the door after him.
2. He got out of the car and closed the door behind him.

Is it correct ?

Answer (score 1):

(My answer assumes both "he" and "him" refer to the same person.)

1. The position of the person is ambiguous in *He closed the door behind him*. It may mean the person entered the space and closed the door, or he exited the space and closed the door. The context would have to provide additional information, as in your example *He got in the car and closed the door*.
2. *He closed the door after him* is also ambiguous. My sense is that *after* is more commonly used when the person is exiting the space, but the words do not require that meaning.

For the car examples, "behind him" and "after him" are unnecessary because the examples specify the position of the person relative to the car. *He got in the car and closed the door* is enough; "after him" or "behind him" is not needed unless you want to emphasize the act of closing the door.

Comment: Yes, on its own, the sentence 'he closed the door behind him' tells you precisely nothing about where the person is, beyond the fact that they have just passed through a door. Surrounding sentences are needed to give context about which direction the person was going.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree with kevinbatchcom. My further two cents are...

When there's only one door, we are least bothered to specify the position. `He closed the door` and that's it!

If you still want to specify the position of *door* (and not him!), better use clear words for the direction. Say, in a small room, he entered and there are two doors. In front of him and behind him. Then, *"He closed the door that was behind him **or** front of him."* serves the purpose.